# My function works with scalar, but not an array. What can I do to overcome this problem?

Tags: python, numpy

```
def diffusitivity(z):
   a=1
   if (0<=z and z<1.0/2.0):
        temp=2*(1+a)*(1+2*a)/(a^2)*z*((1-2*z)**(1/a))
        return temp
   elif (1/2<=z and z<=1):
        temp=2*(1+a)*(1+2*a)/(a^2)*(1-z)*((2*z-1)**(1/a))
        return temp
   else:
        return 0
```

It works fine when the input z is a single number. But it does not work when z is a numpy array. I think it is the logical operator that does not work with numpy array. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What does not work? Show a testable example which does not work and show the error

Comment: The statements `(0<=z and z<1.0/2.0)` and `(1/2<=z and z<=1)` won't work with arrays. For example, `a = np.array([1,3,8])`, then `a < 2` will give you `array([True, False, False])`. If you do `&` on two arrays, you get an array (if you use `and` you get an error). To avoid it, you have to use `any()` or `all()` (or something else) to reduce that array to a scalar before using it with `if`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that ^ is not **

Comment: most likely you are getting valueerror about ambiguous booleans.

Comment: The python `if` doesn't work with arrays. It branches only once, without any sort of iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your way of thinking a bit:

```
d = numpy.zeros_like(z)

m = z >= 0
m &= z < 0.5
d[m] = -24*z[m]**2 + 12*z[m]

m = z >= 0.5
m &= z <= 1
d[m] = -24*z[m]**2 + 36*z[m] - 12
```

The equations simplify quite a bit with a=1 in your example, but the idea is to use a mask to selectively apply the conditions (then reuse to save memory).